# What else am I meant to add?

Tags: support, specific-question

I made a question about parasites [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38616/whats-a-good-structure-for-biological-parasitic-mind-control) that i admit was kind of vague at the start but after JDlugos and Brythan asked me to, I edited it accordingly, giving the information they asked about an hour after they asked it, (which you can see in the comments) and three hours later my question is put on hold. I don't know what more to add to the question and the question isn't vague (at least not as vague as my other questions which have never had problems). If I'm wrong tell me because I don't know what to 'fix' here.

This is not a question on why it hasn't been reopened, I am well aware it has only been 2 hours since being put on hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the question was already in the "close" queue before the edits were made and the reviewers weren't as careful as they could have been. I agree it's now clear what you are asking, and in fact the question is now open again.

Comment: thankyou for the answer